# Problems to extract data with JSON from API Google Analytics

Tags: azure-data-factory, google-analytics-api

in this days I worked with API from Google Analytics for extract data to my DataLake using DataFactory; but, on the JSON generation page I can´t put two filters for my dimensions, when I write the JSON manually and run my pipeline I only get an error menssage... My JSON looks like this:

`{ "dimensions": [{ "name": "date"}, {"name": "XXXX" },{"name": "customEvent:XXXX"}], "metrics": [{"name":"eventCount" } ], "dateRanges": [ {"startDate": "@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-01')}","endDate": "@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}" }], "dimensionFilter": { "operator": "AND","filters": [ { "stringFilter": { "matchType": "EXACT","value": "XXXXX" },"fieldName": "customEvent:XXXX"}, {"stringFilter": { "matchType": "EXACT", "value": "XXXXX"},"fieldName": "customEvent:XXXX"}}

My result:
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=RestCallFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Rest call failed with client error, status code 400 BadRequest, please check your activity settings

Comment: Can you provide your linked service configurations and source configurations?

Answer (score 0):

community

I found a way to solve it!

Thanks!

Comment: If you found a solution please post it so that everyone can learn from it.